# Sentencia SQL Dinámica con valores de un array PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ms-access

Veamos, tengo un montón de datos de una tabla MS Access recogidos en un array. Digamos que cada registro tiene 3 campos. De esa forma, tengo entonces en el array:

Índice 0-2: corresponden a los campos del registro 1. 
Índice 3-5: corresponden a los campos del registro 2.

Y así sucesivamente.

Es decir, para que se entienda mejor:

Campos de la BBDD: "id", "nombre", "apellido".
Valores del array: "1", "Jose", "Fernandez", "2", "Marta", "Garcia", "3", "Julian", "Ramirez" etc.

El caso es que ahora quiero insertarlos en una tabla de MySQL. Y claro, no sé cómo hacer el INSERT. Porque la sintaxis sería

```
INSERT INTO "nombre_tabla" ("columnna1", "columna2", ...)
VALUES ("valor1", "valor2", ...);
```

En columna1, columna 2 etc. no hay duda. El tema es que no sé cómo insertar los valores del array porque:

VALUES ("¿?").

-No puedo poner VALUES("1", "Jose", "Fernandez") etc. porque no son valores dinámicos.
-Pero, tampoco puedo poner en la sentencia SQL algo del estilo valores[0], valores[1] etc. porque hoy tengo 3 campos por registro, pero mañana pueden ser 4, 5 o más.

Por tanto, mi pregunta es... ¿Cómo puedo insertar valores dinámicos en una sentencia SQL de un array, siendo los valores y los índices dinámicos (con esto último de los índices me refiero a que ahora sabes que los tres primeros son del mismo registro, y los tres siguientes del siguiente registro, y así, pero que en un futuro si aumentan los campos del registro, no serán los tres primeros índices del primer registro, sino que serán 4, 5 o más).

ACTUALIZACIÓN 1:

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($datosToInsertMS); $i++) { 
            $queryToInsertMSdiffpedido="INSERT INTO pedidos(*) VALUES ("$datosToInsertMS[$i].",)";
        }
```

ACTUALIZACIÓN 2:

```
  for ($i=0; $i < count($datosToInsertMS); $i++) { 
            $queryToInsertMSdiffpedido="INSERT INTO pedidos(*) VALUES ('','$datosToInsertMS[$i]')";
        }
```

He llegado a la conclusión de que se puede hacer así, lo que no sé ahora es cómo meterle ahí la variable $datosToInsertMS[$i]. Básicamente quiero insertarle la variable de forma correcta (ahora me da error) y que tras la variable me ponga una coma, y que cuando sea la última variable (para que no dé error) me meta el valor correspondiente pero no ponga coma, sino punto y coma, para que sea la sentencia correcta sintácticamente.

No sé si con la actualización 2 voy bien, al menos el editor de código no me ha dado error. Ahora bien, me sale al ejecutar el error de Array to String conversion. Sé que es porque estoy tratando un array como un string, pero al tener que hacer el parseo en la sentencia SQL, estoy perdidillo respecto a cómo hacerlo.

ACTUALIZACIÓN 3:

```
 $GroupByRegisterDatosToInsertFromMS=array_chunk($datosToInsertFromMS, 49);
```

Con el var_dump me devuelve esto:

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(4) { [0]=> array(49) { ["Marketplace"]=> string(3) "WEB" ["IdPedido"]=> string(10) "PJSDJKSDKS" ["fecha"]=> string(19) "2020-10-08 00:00:00" ["nombre cliente"]=> string(23) "RONALDO NAZARIO DA LIMA" ["direccion"]=> string(16) "CALLE BRASIL, 23" ["DNI"]=> string(9) "89454081C" ["cp"]=> string(5) "19872" ["poblacion"]=> string(11) "ZAMORA" ["provincia"]=> string(11) "ZAMORA" ["telefono"]=> string(9) "876482913" ["idarticulo"]=> string(9) "PSJASJDJC" ["descripcion"]=> string(12)
```

El código que me devuelve el fallo de array to string conversion es el siguiente:

```
   foreach ($GroupByRegisterDatosToInsertFromMS as $row) {
            $sql="INSERT INTO Pedidos (". implode(",",$arrayColumns).") VALUES ('".implode("','",$row)."');";
        }
```

Muchas gracias, saludos.

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende, por favor explícate mejor poniendo ejemplos concretos basados en los datos. Y también, dado que has abierto un montón de preguntas muchas de las cuales han sido respondidas, considera dedicar un poco de tiempo a indicar aquellas que hayan sido resueltas. Este sitio existe para que las preguntas que sirven a uno puedan servir a otros en el futuro.

Comment: Muchas gracias por el feedback. Acabo de editar la pregunta. Respecto a las preguntas anteriores, no sabía que tenía que cerrarlas. Entiendo que se cierran seleccionando aquella que más te ha ayudado a resolver la pregunta que hiciste. Ya he hecho eso. Muchas gracias :)

Comment: No me refería a cerrarlas, sino a indicar aquellas que han sido resueltas, marcando como aceptada la respuesta que ha servido más para resolver el problema, cosa que has hecho. Las preguntas se cierran mediante votos o de otros modos, cuando son duplicadas o no se adaptan al formato del sitio.

Comment: En cuanto a esta pregunta, ¿por qué no consideras generar tu array organizado en el origen? Existen los arrays asociativos, que te permitirían tener algo así: `$mData=array( array("id"=>1, "nombre"=>"NA", "apellido"=>"AA"),  array("id"=>2, "nombre"=>"NB", "apellido"=>"AB") );` En ese array cada fila viene en un sub-array y lo podrás usar sin complicaciones y sin códigos oscuros.

Comment: Ese array que tengo viene generado de una consulta de todos los campos de una BBDD a partir de un IdPedido. Honestamente, no sabía como sacar los valores en forma de array asociativo, y que además los campos variarán con el tiempo. Esta forma me parecía la más reusable.

Comment: Muchas veces los problemas que tienes hoy son secuelas de hechos del pasado, lo mismo pasa en programación, si en la etapa anterior no hiciste las cosas debidamente, tendrás problemas en la etapa actual. Entonces rectifica lo que hiciste mal y todo irá mejor y será todo más simple.

Comment: El tema es que me han "obligado" por así decirlo a hacerlo de esta forma.

Comment: Bueno no entiendo mucho eso de que te han obligado, generalmente el código corre en background, por lo que eres libre para implementarlo como quieras, buscando siempre la forma más óptima. Si no hay alternativa, puedes recorrer el array e ir controlando las iteracciones cada `X` campos para ir partiendo las filas, pero esto sería implementar un código *oscuro*, en el sentido de que si el array original no está perfectamente organizando (con cada fila de `X` en `X`) puede ocurrir un desastre en la inserción de datos.

Comment: El tema es que realmente no puedes organizar tampoco cada fila de X en X, porque los campos ahora son x pero en un futuro serán más, con lo cual...¿No existe alguna forma de que automáticamente vaya metiendo x campos y que simplemente cuando acabe la fila de inserción en la bbdd vaya metiendo en la siguiente fila y así?

Comment: Es lo que te quise decir precisamente, supongamos que tengas un solo array con todo mezclado, pero cada tres campos es una fila, algo así: `array(1, "f1c2", "f1c3", 2, "f2c2", "f2c3", 3, "f3c2", "f3c3")` puedes ir leyendo ese array, agrupando internamente por cada 3 campos, siendo que cada fila viene así (cada fila viene de `X` en `X`, de `3` en `3` en este caso). Si en un futuro los campos vienen de `4` en `4` pues lo mismo, organizas de `4`en `4`... Lo que me extraña es que tengas libertad para montar este rollo y no para organizar mejor los datos en el origen. ¿?

Comment: Soy un estudiante en prácticas, supongo que comprenderás mejor ahora lo de "me han obligado". Respecto a lo de organizarlo internamente, ¿Cómo lo organizarías? Porque realmente no se me ocurre una forma, es decir, lo que dices de organizarlo de 3 en 3 lo comprendo pero no sabría implementarlo en código. Gracias.

Comment: De los 49 objetos que hay en el array anidado es preciso ver al menos uno completo para tener una idea de tu estructura. Y ver como cierra el objeto. Parece que ya tienes un array anidado, nada que ver con tu planteamiento inicial. Creo que es mejor que abras una nueva pregunta. Y, si los datos que se muestran ahí son reales es mejor que los cambies por datos ficticios. Puedes escribir `echo "<pre>";` antes del var_dump para que salga identado, así es más fácil de analizar.

Comment: Son datos ficticios, no hay problema. Abriré una nueva pregunta entonces. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como ya he comentado laaaargamente, puedes recurrir a un código *oscuro* para organizar los datos. Por *oscuro* me refiero a que si hay algún error (por ejemplo, que no todos los subgrupos vengan de `N` en `N`), esta lógica se va a romper y va a ser desastrosa. Por eso siempre es mejor organizar los elementos en el origen, acordes al mejor modo de usarlos en el destino.

Si no hay otra alternativa, puedes usar funciones como [`array_chunk()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-chunk.php) para identificar los sub-grupos.

Aquí te dejo un código con comentarios *in situ*. Si entiendes lo explicado, organizar los `INSERT` será relativamente fácil.

```
/*
    Tu array general con todas las filas mezcladas de 3 en 3
*/
$mGeneral=array(1, "f1c2", "f1c3", 2, "f2c2", "f2c3", 3, "f3c2", "f3c3");
/*
    Lo divides en grupos de 3 con array_chunk
    Si fueran grupos de N, cambias 3 por el valor de N
*/
$mPartial = array_chunk($mGeneral, 3);

/*
    Este es un array auxiliar que puede servirte 
    para identificar los nombres de colunma
    y puede ser muy útil para armar el INSERT de forma dinámica
*/
$mColumns=array('id','nombre','apellido');

/*
    Lees el chunk construyendo un INSERT con la ayuda de $mColumns
    y usando implode en cada sub-grupo
*/
foreach ($mPartial as $row){
    $sql="INSERT INTO laTabla (". implode(",",$mColumns).") VALUES ('".implode("','",$row)."');";
    echo $sql.PHP_EOL;
}
```

**Salida:**

```
INSERT INTO laTabla (id,nombre,apellido) VALUES ('1','f1c2','f1c3');
INSERT INTO laTabla (id,nombre,apellido) VALUES ('2','f2c2','f2c3');
INSERT INTO laTabla (id,nombre,apellido) VALUES ('3','f3c2','f3c3');
```

### PD:

Dado que has dicho que eres estudiante. Si tienes limitaciones en cuanto al uso de funciones como `array_chunk` puedes implementar algo parecido llevando un contador interno en el bucle.

Comment: Estoy utilizando este código pero adaptado a mis variables:  foreach ($GroupByRegisterDatosToInsertFromMS as $row) {
            $sql="INSERT INTO Pedidos (". implode(",",$arrayColumns).") VALUES ('".implode("','",$row)."');";
        } Sin embargo, me da error Array to string conversion. ¿En qué estoy fallando? En teoría con el implode no debería ocurrir eso.

Comment: @Sergio muestra en la pregunta qué estructura tiene `$GroupByRegisterDatosToInsertFromMS` mostrando un trozo de lo que te imprima esto: `var_dump($GroupByRegisterDatosToInsertFromMS);` Y, te aconsejo que evites crear nombres de variable kiloooooooooooooooooométricos. Con llamarle `$groupedData` o algo así ya se sabe que son datos agrupados.

Comment: Lo acabo de hacer. He editado la pregunta con la información que me dijiste. Muchas gracias, saludos.